# How to add same server side script in asp.net on all pages?

Tags: asp.net

I got this script from a developer to put it on my website for changing the phone numbers dynamically.

```
    <script runat="server">
        public string getPhoneNumber()
        {
            string strPhone = "";
            if (!(Session["Phone"] == null))
            {
                strPhone = Session["Phone"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                searchphone.GetPhone obj = new searchphone.GetPhone();
                string strURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

                if (Request.QueryString["s"] != null && Request.QueryString["P"] != null)
                    strPhone = obj.GetPhoneNumber(Request.QueryString["s"], Request.QueryString["p"]);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPhone))
                    Session["Phone"] = strPhone;
                else
                    strPhone = obj.GetPhoneNumber(strURL);
            }
            return strPhone;
        }
    </script>
```

Logic is in a dll file and there is a namespace also which needs to be included on every page. Code is working fine.

But my problem is he has asked me to put this script on every page manually. Also its not working when I put the script and import the namespace on the master page and want to use the getphonenumber method(<% =getPhoneNumber() %>) on the content pages to track and change the phone number based on user sessions.

The objective for this code is to track the users and display the phone number based on that. And i want to include this script once globally so every page can access it and use its getphonenumber method. Thanks.

Comment: if you want it in all the pages place it master page.

Comment: @AntoJSubash read his question, he has tried it

Comment: this is C# code, why dont you move it to an assembly and reference that assembly?

Comment: Why don't you use a `public class` and make this method `public static`? Then you can access it from everywhere. You don't need an instance of the page anyway. You can get all objects like `Session` or `Request` via `HttpContext.Current`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to place this function on the masterpage. Then access the function on your page.

### Masterpage:

```
public string getPhoneNumber()
{
    string strPhone = "";
    if (!(Session["Phone"] == null))
    {
        strPhone = Session["Phone"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        searchphone.GetPhone obj = new searchphone.GetPhone();
        string strURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        if (Request.QueryString["s"] != null && Request.QueryString["P"] != null)
            strPhone = obj.GetPhoneNumber(Request.QueryString["s"], Request.QueryString["p"]);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPhone))
            Session["Phone"] = strPhone;
        else
            strPhone = obj.GetPhoneNumber(strURL);
    }
    return strPhone;
}
```

### Page

```
<%= ((MasterPageType)this.Master).getPhoneNumber() %>
```

Where `MasterPageType` is the type name of your master page.

---

Another way to achieve this is by creating a static class (new file):

### Static class

```
public static class SessionTools
{
    public static string getPhoneNumber()
    {
        string strPhone = "";
        if (!(HttpContext.Current.Session["Phone"] == null))
        {
            strPhone = HttpContext.Current.Session["Phone"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            searchphone.GetPhone obj = new searchphone.GetPhone();
            string strURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["s"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["P"] != null)
                strPhone = obj.GetPhoneNumber(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["s"], HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["p"]);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPhone))
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Phone"] = strPhone;
            else
                strPhone = obj.GetPhoneNumber(strURL);
        }
        return strPhone;
    }
}
```

### Page

```
<%= SessionTools.getPhoneNumber() %>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. But i am not an expert in asp.net. Could you please elaborate the masterpagetype part?

Comment: What's the name of your master page? Do you have a code behind (.cs) file for you masterpage?

Comment: Its LandingPage.master. Yeah i have a code behind .cs file also.

Comment: Then you should use `<%= ((LandingPage)this.Master).getPhoneNumber() %>`

Comment: Its showing a red squiggly line under LandingPage. On hovering its shows this error "The type or namespace name 'LandingPage' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Is LandinPage.master in a different folder? What's the namespace of the codebehdind class? Go open the .cs file from your masterpage. In there you should find the namespace and class name

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is there a way we can add this code in a usercontrol or in any class file once so that all pages can access this getphonenumber method by default? Because there are 15-20 master pages and i don't want to edit the code in so many places.

Comment: You could make a static function out of it and access that one. Or create a basic masterpage that all other masterpages then derive from and place the function in the base masterpage

Comment: Will that function be accessible all over the project?

Comment: i created a new class file with the same code as you have put it here. But its showing  red squibbly under Request and Session. Do i have to include other namespaces?

Comment: You have to include the usings for them. WHen you moove your mouse over those red squibbly lines you can popup a menu where can choose which type to import.

Comment: Right now i have these namespaces included by default. using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

Comment: @GauravNanda I had an error in my static class, check edited answer. I forgot to add HttpContext.Current